# Is there a way to tell WebStorm that string is CSS

Tags: css, string, typescript, autocomplete, webstorm

I have some React components written in TypeScript that contain a string prop for CSS classes. For example:

**DEFINITION**

```
function MyComponent({css}:{css:string}) {
    // use css string...
}
```

**USAGE**

```html
<MyComponent css="text-blue-100 flex flex-row"/>
```

Is there a way to tell WebStorm that the `css` field should be interpreted as CSS rather than an arbitrary string so that I can get auto-complete working for that field (just like I can in a standard HTML tag)?

Comment: Try Language Injections (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`) -- this is how `style` attribute in HTML tags is handled for example.  See if that can be used for **classes** completion... 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-language-injections.html#configure-injection-rules 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/language-injections-settings.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was the first place I looked too, but as far as I can tell that's not an option. It will let me write CSS in a string (as in declare classes with attributes) but not interpret a string as a series of CSS class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite hacky .. but seems to work. How well it works: most likely not as good as native `class` attribute in HTML tags.

Code sample in action (plain HTML file, if that makes any difference):

[image: An example]

**The actual injection rule.** The idea is to trick the IDE that it is a `class` attribute here... so we are injecting HTML with prefix and suffix bits:

[image]

Comment: Works pretty well as far as I can tell! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No way unfortunately; the only workaround I can suggest is injecting `JQuery-CSS` language into your attribute:

[image]

But note that you would then need to enter a dot to see the classes completion - with this language injected, the classes are expected to start with a dot, HTML tags are suggested otherwise:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up and for the workaround. Unfortunately that option won't work for me but hopefully it can help someone else.