WebStorm autocomplete for Tailwind CSS outside className?
I have a React component with a className attribute.
I'm at a point where I need to add some logic to decide what classes to include in className based on the component's state.
I tried classnames but it looks like WebStorm cannot autocomplete class names outside the className attribute.
Is there any way to get CSS autocompletion working (Tailwind CSS specifically) outside the className attribute with WebStorm?

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67923363/783119 -- might work (I do not work with React, so cannot test it; only in a plain HTML or supported template languages)

Thanks @LazyOne ! This is close but the Tailwind classes are not showing up for some reason.
